# TCP kernel implementation

Tags: linux, tcp, kernel

I have developed a new TCP congestion avoidance algorithm which I want to implement in the linux kernel and test its performance. But for this I need to understand the existing TCP kernel (2.6) implementation. How do you suggest I should proceed with this? Please suggest some articles/books etc which can give me a head start. I know I will have to eventually dive into the source code but it would be helpful if I at least know broad implementation aspects and how to navigate through the code.

Answer (score 9):

I would just dive directly into the source code of the simpler congestion avoidance algorithms already in the kernel. They're in the `net/ipv4` directory, and [tcp_vegas.c](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/net/ipv4/tcp_vegas.c?v=2.6.25.8) is pretty thoroughly commented. You may also wish to look at [tcp_highspeed.c](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/net/ipv4/tcp_highspeed.c) and [tcp_bic.c](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/net/ipv4/tcp_bic.c) because they're fairly simple (fewer than 250 lines of code).